# Zoom transition in PowerPoint

Tags: animation, presentation-design, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using PowerPoint for a presentation (I know that other tools may be better, but not in this case).

In a transition between two slides, I've to zoom part of an image (which is a simple tree structure, with a root and two children nodes/leaves) and pass to the next slide, like if the next slide extends the concept of one leaf.

How is it possible to do that?

I tried with growing the tree image, setting the leaf to the center/middle, but I'd prefer using a better technique (a transition instead of a group of animations) or a proper plugin.

Comment: I haven't touched powerpoint in years, but a google search hits gave up this link: ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-pan-and-zoom-effects-in-powerpoint-HA010232631.aspx ) With some careful pan and zoom and then a normal transition to the end result, you can probably get what you want.

Comment: Indeed I've "solved" using a technique like the one you linked.
It's not "user-friendly" (for the slides maker) and it takes some time, but it works...

Comment: I would say that if you had the option to, use a different software. There's plenty of free software that allows you to create professional presentations that do things like this. In powerPoint I see no other way of doing it than  using a group of animations.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with [lawndartcatcher](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/575/lawndartcatcher).
There's not going to be a good way of doing this without a good amount of custom animation.

They quick 2 minutes job is to create copies of your node and scale them up, then have them zoom into the slide one after the other until it takes up however much of the slide you want, and then to transition to your next slide.

The easier alternative of course is to use something other than powerPoint, but as you've mentioned, that's not an option.

Answer (score 1):

In 2018, you can use the PowerPoint Morph transition (not available back in 2012) to zoom:

1. Duplicate the slide containing the graphics you want to zoom in on.
2. Enlarge the graphics on the duplicate slide.
3. Apply Morph transition.

You can progressively fade-in additional detail, either as part of the Morph transition, or subsequently.

For examples of using the Morph transition to zoom, see this video that I created in PowerPoint: "[The Lifecycle of an IMS Connect Transaction](https://youtu.be/ygG9D6mfLDA)" (in particular, the panning'n'zooming from 9 minutes 15 seconds onwards).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a simple way to do this with this amount of precision in PowerPoint without doing a lot of custom animations (I've done these for a couple of presentations; spending a couple of hours on a single animation isn't uncommon).

You may be able to do this a little more easily with Keynote - is that an option for you?

Comment: No, sadly I can't use nothing than PPT for this presentation...
Anyway, just for sharing knowledge, also prezi.com and impress.js HTML framework (in the latter case, impress.js not an URL) allow to do it easily.